# Menu em HTML/CSS centralizado

Tags: css, aplicação-web, menu, html

Preciso de um help com um código não conheço muito sobre *HTML* e *CSS*, estou aprendendo aos poucos, e preciso de uma ajuda.

> Inicio Código *HTML/CSS*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html  xml:lang="pt" lang="pt">

<head>
<title>Menu Horizontal</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

#menu ul {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color:#EDEDED;
list-style:none;
font:80% Tahoma;
}

#menu ul li { display: inline; }

#menu ul li a {
background-color:#EDEDED;
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom:3px solid #EDEDED;
padding: 2px 10px;
float:left;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
background-color:#D6D6D6;
color: #6D6D6D;
border-bottom:3px solid #EA0000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
<li><a href="">Artigos</a></li>
<li><a href="">Estudos</a></li>
<li><a href="">Diretório</a></li>
<li><a href="">CURSO</a></li>
<li><a href="">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este e o código que tenho, porem não consigo colocar esse menu sempre centralizado na pagina, conseguiriam me ajudar.

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve colocar no `#menu ul`, `#menu ul li` e `#menu ul li a` as seguintes alterações. Nota que `display: inline;` não lhe permite dar `comprimento/altura` ao elemento, `float: left;` é desnecessário também.

```css
body {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

#menu ul {
padding:0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
background-color:#EDEDED;
list-style:none;
font:80% Tahoma;
}

#menu ul li { display: inline-block; height: 100%;}

#menu ul li a {
background-color:#EDEDED;
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom:3px solid #EDEDED;
padding: 2px 10px;
display: block;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
background-color:#D6D6D6;
color: #6D6D6D;
border-bottom:3px solid #EA0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
<li><a href="">Artigos</a></li>
<li><a href="">Estudos</a></li>
<li><a href="">Diretório</a></li>
<li><a href="">CURSO</a></li>
<li><a href="">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```